# TikZ text node and edge position in TikZit

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I am using the [TikZit](https://tikzit.github.io) application to construct a diagram containing nodes that "contain" or "consist of" only text (formatted with color, etc.) and that are connected by various edges. When inputing the text as the `label` argument, the connecting edge encroaches into the middle of the text, like this:

[image]

Here is the source code generated by TikZit:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{nodelayer}
        \node [style=none] (0) at (-2.5, 7) {Hello world!};
        \node [style=green dot] (1) at (1.75, 5) {};
        \node [style=red dot] (2) at (2.25, -0.75) {};
        \node [style=none] (3) at (-3, -2) {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{edgelayer}
        \draw (0.center) to (1);
        \draw [in=30, out=45, looseness=2.25] (1) to (2);
        \draw (3.center) to (2);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I was able to use the `label={POSITION:TEXT}` option to modify the default behavior

`\node [style=none, label={above=Hello \textcolor{blue}{World!}}] (0) at (-2.5, 7) {};`

which renders

[image]

which is what I am wanting.

The problem is that I do not want to manually input the `position` parameter for each node and I do not know how to set up a node style that will automatically position the edge connection relative to the text node without having to specify the `position` in each case. To put it in question form: Is there a way to set up a node style that will automatically position the connecting edge on the "outside" of the node relative to the text like the second image above?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't know TikZit, but what you want will be the default if you don't put the text inside the label, but use it as the text contents. So, don't use `\node[label={above:Hello}] at (0,0) {};`, but `\node at (0,0) {Hello};`. I don't know what `style=none` does. Can you remove it?